# pypdf mergepage issue

Tags: python, pypdf

I want to add pdf watermark using pypdf lib, code below:

```
def add_wm(pdf_in, pdf_out):
    wm_file = open("watermark.pdf", "rb")
    pdf_wm = PdfFileReader(wm_file)
    pdf_output = PdfFileWriter()
    input_stream = open(pdf_in, "rb")
    pdf_input = PdfFileReader(input_stream)
    pageNum = pdf_input.getNumPages()
    #print pageNum
    for i in range(pageNum):
        page = pdf_input.getPage(i)
        page.mergePage(pdf_wm.getPage(0)) # !! here is fail if has chinese character
        page.compressContentStreams()
        pdf_output.addPage(page)

    output_stream = open(pdf_out, "wb")
    pdf_output.write(output_stream)
    output_stream.close()
    input_stream.close()
    wm_file.close()

    return True
```

The issue is if `page = pdf_input.getPage(i)` page has Chinese characters,  `page.mergePage` will be raise exception and cause failure. How do I work around this?

Answer (score 1):

The Python library pdfrw also supports [watermarking](https://github.com/pmaupin/pdfrw/blob/master/examples/watermark.py).  If it does not work for your particular PDF, please email it to me (address at github) and I will investigate -- I am the pdfrw author.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when i was watermarking with PyPdf2 1.25.1 .

pdfrw as Patrick suggested isn't working for my PDF (works for word documents exported as pdf but not for scanned documents i guess).

Updating to the newest version of PyPDF2 (for me this is 1.26.0) fixed this bug.

For more information see [PyPDF2 issue #176](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/issues/176)